# htaccess rewrite any domain to www+SSL with CloudFlare sniffer

Tags: .htaccess, cloudflare

I run a couple of Wordpress-based websites which get reverse proxied via CloudFlare. I would like to redirect bare domain (but not subdomain!) to 'www.domain' and, if CloudFlare is enabled, then enforce SSL (redirect to 'https://'). But if CloudFlare is disabled, then it should only do redirection to 'www' over standard HTTP.

Note this should be achieved with as few redirections as possible, to minimise the number of requests. Also, the code should be reusable for any domain.

To-date, I have come up with the following code - but it has a problem, on which below.

```
# BEGIN Redirect to www & SSL
    RewriteEngine On
# If CloudFlare headers are not set, rewrite bare domain to 'www':
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:CF-Visitor} !=='"scheme":"http"'
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:CF-Visitor} !=='"scheme":"https"'
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
    RewriteRule .* http://www\.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
# If CloudFlare headers are set, rewrite bare domain to 'www' via SSL:
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:CF-Visitor} '"scheme":"http"' [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:CF-Visitor} '"scheme":"https"'
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
    RewriteRule .* https://www\.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
# If CloudFlare headers are set, rewrite non-SSL to SSL:
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:CF-Visitor} '"scheme":"http"'
    RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
# END Redirect to www & SSL
```

This appears to work in a browser, but header sniffer shows an unacceptable number or redirects. I am using Web-sniffer and it shows that requests first get 301 redirected to www, then subsequently 301 to SSL. Not sure why, but this should normally go in one 301 redirect - directly to 'https://www'.

Also, I am not entirely sure of my CloudFlare sniffer.

Any advice will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's only for one domain ? Because it is much easier to test a subdomain when using the domain name.

Comment: The idea was to have the code reusable, i.e., it should not specify the domain name (also because of domain aliasing on a single site). Currently the code runs on http://jasminum.ltd.uk (via CF) and http://growyourcharity.net (directly), feel free to test.

Comment: In your question you say "but not subdomain". But you never test that...

Comment: I did test, and subdomains (other than 'www') worked fine. Don't get me wrong: I am not a programmer, just a webmaster experimenting with bits of code in his search for the desired functionality.

Comment: I mean that there is no test in your .htaccess. You add www without testing if a subdomain is used or not

Comment: True, but somehow it does not cause problems.
I need to add that all my Wordpress installations have the official CloudFlare plugin active. Jasminum.ltd.uk additionally has another plugin to correct http background image URL to https, due to theme design flaw.

Comment: "it does not cause problems" except "an unacceptable number or redirects"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
# BEGIN Redirect to www & SSL
    RewriteEngine On
# If CloudFlare headers are not set, rewrite bare domain to 'www':
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:CF-Visitor} !scheme
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\..{2,6}$
    RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
# If CloudFlare headers are set, rewrite bare domain to 'www' via SSL:
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:CF-Visitor} scheme
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\..{2,6}$
    RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
# If CloudFlare headers are set, rewrite non-SSL to SSL:
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:CF-Visitor} '"scheme":"http"'
    RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
# END Redirect to www & SSL
```

Comment: This one does not seem to rewrite to 'www'

Comment: Your code seems to only work on global TLDs, those with three-letter domain endings (.com, .org), but not on second-level domains (like .ltd.uk, .org.uk). I aliased various domains to a single site and this is what it shows.

Comment: Now works on second-level domains but still does not work on two-letter TLDs (.eu, .uk, .fr)

Comment: Yes sorry it's ok now